# Karma throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" for Angular and JQuery Map file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dictionary, syntax-error, karma-runner

I am trying to write Unit Tests using karma. My application has a dependency on Angular and JQuery that I have installed via bower

```
"dependencies": {
     .....
     "angular": "1.2.16",
     .....
     "jquery": "~1.11.2",
     .....
}
```

Here AngularJS and JQuery are bundled with .map file which contains some set of key-value pair. To load these map files into Karma, I found out a plugin called `karma-sourcemap-loader`. I have used the following configuration for karma i.e. karma.conf.js

```
  files: [
        {pattern: 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',included:true},
        {pattern: 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map',watched: true, served: true, included: true},
        {pattern: 'vendor/angular/angular.min.js',included:true},
        {pattern: 'vendor/angular/angular.min.js.map',watched: true, served: true, included: true},
        ......
    ],
  preprocessors: {
       '**/*.js': ['sourcemap']
  },
```

When I checked up with chrome, the console has printed out the following error

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:9876/base/vendor/angular/angular.min.js.map?5ff6288d0408a1b41c74b7bd7541d68865d1e3f9`

On Console it shows up
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` for Chrome

`SyntaxError: Parse error` for PhantomJS

Also I am using RequireJS to import files. Can anybody please help me by providing a proper way to include map files in karma ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one of my friend had made use of RequireJS to load JQuery and AngularJS. Now when I tried using the RequireJS configuration file with karma, the minified version was also loaded. This created an issue with karma. So I made use of `test-main.js` ([Karma RequireJS Doc](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html)) and I added up a requirement for `require-config.js` itself. Thus all the dependencies would be loaded up by `require-config.js`

```
 require(['/base/<path>/require-config.js'], function(){
      .........
      .........
      require.config({
            baseUrl: /base,
            deps: allTestFiles,
            callback: window.__karma__.start
      });
 }
```

Thank you all for having a look at this problem.